# html is not including link and scripts when included through php

Tags: php, html

I m beginner in coding with php, I came across include and require statements and started implementing them. I included a HTML file in my PHP file. The sample code of my HTML file is (just to illustrate the scenario not he actual code) -

```
<html>
   <link href="some/css/file.css" />
   <script src="javascript/file.js"></script>
   <body>
        <!--body of the document-->
   </body>
</html>
```

code for php file -

```
<?php
   include("file.html");
?>
```

And the output is plain html without any effect of css and javascript on it although i included it in the HTML file. So, why is that happening?

if i write php in the following way-

```
<style>
 <?php include("some/css/file.css");?>
</style>

<script>
   <?php include("javascript/file.js"); ?>
</script>

<?php
   include("file.html");
?>
```

it works fine..... But if i want to include 10 css files and 10 js files... it will be an overhead to include the files individually.....

And why the first approach does not work?

Thanks for reading.......

Comment: you add each file manually if your file is different, no other way

Comment: thank you @Bhargav, and why html dont link those files??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this way

create a html file which will `include .css and .js file` and this html file you add on your `php` page like

**file.html** `//have .js and and .css file`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some/css/file.css" />
<script src="javascript/file.js"></script>
```

and this `file.html include`  on `php` like

```
<?php
   include('file.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with you could make a `defines.php` file and include it in your `index.php`. What you could add is this: `define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));`

This means when you enter for example this: `$this->basePath =  BASE_PATH . '/lib/company/Layouts/';` you will always have the right base_path incase you switch servers.

Which means you can change your script to this:

```
<style>
 <?php include __BASE_PATH__ . "some/css/file.css";?>
</style>

<script>
   <?php include __BASE_PATH__ . "javascript/file.js"; ?>
</script>

<?php
   include __BASE_PATH__ . "file.html"; // or include $this->basePath . "file.html"; This depends on how you want to use this. 
?>
```

Somehow you still need to edit your files only once and the `defines.php` could be the solution for your next projects or in future current project.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: I hope this helped you. If you have any questions just ask :). If you feel my answer helped you into the right direction you could mark my answer as the right answer. Good luck trex.

Answer (score 1):

you missed to related the link as stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/css">
```